How can I speed up the processing time when using FFmpeg?
I am using FFmpeg through a batch file to remux my videos from .mkv to .mp4, but it keeps doing it at a 0.6x or 0.3x speed.
As these are huge files ranging anywhere between 1 hour to 10 hours I need it to be kind of fast, especially since I have a lot of them. Is there any way to speed up the processing time?
Here is the current command I am using:
for %%i in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -map 0:v -vcodec libx265 -crf 24 -map 0:a "%%~ni.mp4"

Are there any parameters to keep it at its highest quality for both audio and video while keeping the processing time and file size as low as possible?

?try to copy → for %%i in (*.mkv) do ffmpeg -i "%%i" -map 0:v -map 0:a -c copy "%%~ni.mp4"

You are re-encoding, not remuxing.

sorry yes, i do want to copy however the file size is too large ranging anywhere between 30gb and 700gb

The only real way to speed up the process is to use multiple computers. You're not gonna find anything better than ffmpeg -i input.mkv output.mp4 for what you need to do. If it could be faster they'd already make it go as fast as it can. I sometimes get less than x1 speed. There's no trick to prevent that. If you wanted it to be faster you'd have to at least sacrifice quality.
